# Connecting the html form to the CRUD operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, frontend

I have created a backend application using JavaScript, NodeJS, ExpressJS and MongoDB that uses simple CRUD operations but I’m wondering how I set the target of submitting the form, to the database.
Also how would the user access the read and update functionality

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you can do this in two ways:

You can use a third-party API, like a REST API, to perform your CRUD operations. You can use the browser API to perform your CRUD operations.

Option 1:

In this case, you will have a frontend application and a backend application. The frontend application will be in charge of the view (how the user will see the data) and the backend application will be in charge of the data (CRUD operations).

If you are new to this, I would suggest you start with this option, as it is easier to implement.

The frontend application will need to perform an HTTP request to the backend application, when the user submits the form, and the backend application will handle the data in the database.

You can learn more about HTTP requests in this tutorial: How to use HTTP requests in JavaScript.

Option 2:

In this case, you will have a single application that will be in charge of both the view and the data.

The frontend application will perform the CRUD operations to the database, using the browser API.

You can learn more about the browser API in this tutorial: How to use the browser API.